# SimpleXML multiple data from another array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, parsing, simplexml

please, I have this code to import data from XML to database:

```
$a = glob('data/*/*.xml');

echo "import kategorie ...... ";
foreach ($a as $i) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("$i") or die ("Chyba: Nemuzu nacist soubor");

    foreach($xml->DocumentElement as $entry) {
        foreach ($entry->hotel as $dataHotel) {
            addCategory("$dataHotel->country", "$dataHotel->location", "$dataHotel->location2");
        }
        foreach ($entry->Popisy as $dataPopisy) {
            addHotel("$dataHotel->hotel", "$dataPopisy->doporuc");
        }
    }
}
echo "OK\n"
```

I can not figure out how to do it - I need in function "addHotel" get data from "hotel" array and from "Popisy" array.
So, I need to get from two at once.

Here is XML structure: http://pastebin.com/TNTpBijg and here http://fmnet.cz/HLS240.xml

Is this possilbe? Thank you very much!

---

Now I tried this:

```
$a = glob('data/*/*.xml');

echo "import kategorie ...... ";
foreach ($a as $i) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("$i") or die ("Chyba: Nemuzu nacist soubor");

    foreach($xml->DocumentElement as $entry) {
        foreach ($entry->hotel as $dataHotel) {
            //addCategory("$dataHotel->country", "$dataHotel->location", "$dataHotel->location2");
            foreach ($entry->Popisy as $dataPopisy) {
               //addHotel("$dataHotel->hotel", "$dataPopisy->doporuc");
                echo "$dataHotel->hotel";
                echo "\n";
                echo "$dataPopisy->doporuc";
                echo "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "OK\n";
```

but output is only: 
import kategorie ...... OK

Comment: How do you decide which `hotel` goes with which `Popisy`? Can you show us a sample of the data, to see the format?

Comment: here is XML structure: http://pastebin.com/TNTpBijg

Comment: In the above link you have a php dump of the SimpleXML variable. Can you show us an example of the raw xml?

Comment: no problem: http://fmnet.cz/HLS240.xml thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can do it by embedding the popisy loop inside the hotel loop or the other way round. Check the code below:

```
$a = glob('data/*/*.xml');

echo "import kategorie ...... ";
foreach ($a as $i) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("$i") or die ("Chyba: Nemuzu nacist soubor");

    foreach($xml->DocumentElement as $entry) {
        foreach ($entry->hotel as $dataHotel) {
            addCategory("$dataHotel->country", "$dataHotel->location", "$dataHotel->location2");
            foreach ($entry->Popisy as $dataPopisy) {
               addHotel("$dataHotel->hotel", "$dataPopisy->doporuc");
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "OK\n"
```

Comment: I treid this method but not working, when I try: in foreach($entry->Popisy....) run echo "$dataHotel->hotel"; or echo "$dataPopisy->doporuc"; echo not working, no output